# CSS multiple animations on the same element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a single `<div>` on my page. red square and I want 2 animations to be applied to it:

1. Move this square on page load
2. Change the colour of the square on mouse hover

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
    .animation {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: red;
        animation-name: anim;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .animation:hover {
        animation-name: hover;
        animation-duration: 1s;

    }

    @keyframes anim {
        from {
        }
        30% {
            transform: translateX(100px);
        }
        70% {
            transform: translate(100px, 100%);
            /*background-color: blue;*/
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(100px, 100%) scale(2, 2) rotate(145deg);
        }
    }

    @keyframes hover {
        from {
        }
        to {
            background:yellow;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="animation">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tbqj4goy/

The problem with it is that when I hover the mouth the first annimation interrupts and starts from the beginning.

Any ideas how to let these annimation collaborate without problems?

Comment: no need a second animation, use a simple transition for the color change

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried this, but I'm just curious is it possible to use multiple annotations, and why if not

Comment: you can and you need to put them in the same animation. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56510103/8620333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.animation {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: anim;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: 1s;
}

.animation:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: 1s;
}

@keyframes anim {
    from {}

    30% {
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }

    70% {
        transform: translate(100px, 100%);
        /*background-color: blue;*/
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(100px, 100%) scale(2, 2) rotate(145deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="animation">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one more question regarding your solution: if I'm moving mouth off the square it immediately becomes red. is it possible to make it animated as well(yellow -> red on mouth off)?

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, I editted it. You just have to add the transition to the original class (without any state)

Answer (score 0):

For change background color you don't need animation, just add background property to :hover;

```css
        .animation {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: red;
            transition: background-color 250ms ease;
            animation: anim 3s forwards;
        }

        .animation:hover {
           background-color: yellow;
        }

        @keyframes anim {
            from {
            }
            30% {
                transform: translateX(100px);
            }
            70% {
                transform: translate(100px, 100%);
                /*background-color: blue;*/
            }
            100% {
                transform: translate(100px, 100%) scale(2, 2) rotate(145deg);
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="animation">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You posted same solution as me later but forgot the transition of the hover.

Comment: First of all i didn't see your comment when I wrote my comment and adding transition only element is enough. You can check code snippet.